# Auto-resetting <select> and catching value updates with a parameter Knockout

Tags: select, knockout.js, reset, computed-observable

I'm using Knockout JS, and I'm trying to create a simple UI where a series of dropdowns are used to fire an action that is dependant on the value with a parameter.

e.g. if I have a page that gives details of two vehicles and I want to assign them to values from a dropdown.

What is the simplest way, using knockout to provide a parameter (to tell me whether it's vehicle one or vehicle two) and have the dropdown reset itself straight after selection.

I've tried the value binding computed observables, but I couldn't get the select to reset itself immediately after selection.

I tried using a standard function with javascript, and the bind function to pass in the parameter, but this didn't help.

http://jsfiddle.net/7U45W/
This is what I have so far, but I have two problems with it:

1. Changing the value of the select doesn't seem to call the `write` function
2. If I fiddle with it enough I can get it to call the write function but then I can't find a way (without resorted to pure DOM manipulation to set `<select>` box back to the first option.

NB I've tried two different ways to bind the updateAssignment function but neither of them seem to work.

Is this something which needs custom bindings or extended bindings? Or is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about whether it's a nice UI (hard to navigate and make selections using the keyboard). That being said, this isn't hard to achieve. Since the `read` value will never change, we need to ensure that subscribers are notified (and thus update the bound DOM elements) when the `write` function is called, even though the `read` value hasn't changed since last time.

The old answer contained a solution using two observables and a manual subscription (which can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/Emca9/). This edited answer (updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Emca9/1/) uses two observables, one of which is a writeable computed observable, since that was requested in the comments.

Bind the `select` element like the following:

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.drivers,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: selectedDriver,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select driver'">
</select>
```

In the `write` function of the computed observable, ensure that subscribers are notified, to ensure they the bindingHandlers update the DOM elements (i.e. the selected option).

```
function CarViewModel(data){
    var self = this;

    // ... removed other properties for brevity

    self.todaysDriver = ko.observable();
    self.selectedDriver = ko.computed({
        read: function(){
            return undefined;
        },
        write: function(newValue){
            if (newValue){
                self.todaysDriver(newValue);
                self.selectedDriver.notifySubscribers();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for showing me this solution which I will look at in more detail but it seems to use a foreach: binding rather than parameter passing to distinguish between the vehicles. I was particularly interested in techniques that involve passing parameters through to computed observable functions -- sorry this wasn't sufficiently emphasised in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "passing parameters through to computed observable functions". A computed observable is not supposed to be a multi parameter function, for that you'd use an ordinary function. If your computed observables needs multiple values to calculate the return value it should read properties on the viewModel (the `this` or `self` object). I have, however, updated the answer to use a writeable computed observable.

Comment: It sounds as if I'm barking up the wrong tree here. Is it possible to use regular functions in place of observables yet still have knockout update the display? I think the reason I'm having trouble is that I'm trying to find ways to re-use functions in the viewModel for multiple <select> boxes on the page. And what I'm starting to see is that Knockout doesn't really work like that?

Comment: In the end thanks to your help I've solved it in a similar way to your revised solution (i.e. computed observables) but I've scrapped the parameter idea and instead I'm just using two different observables - vehicle1SelectedDriver and vehicle2SelectedDriver.

Comment: If you ask me, it would probably be easiest to put those observables on the actual vehicle objects. That's probably where they belong and it will also be a lot easier for you.

Comment: For simplicity in this example I omitted the fact that I'm using the ko.mapping plugin to create my vehicle ViewModels, but having thought about it I could probably still do as you suggest by using a custom mapping on the vehicle objects... an interesting idea